# Validate a form using AJAX, then submit it

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, validation

I'm validating a form using AJAX like this:

```
<script>

        $(function() {

            $("#loginForm").submit(function() {
               var data = $("#loginForm :input").serialize();
               var curl = "../view/index_valid.php";
               $.ajax({
                  url: curl,
                  method: "post",
                  data: data,
                  success: function(data) {
                      if(data==="logged") {
                          return true;
                      } else {
                          return false;
                      }
                  }

               });
               return false;
            }); // end loginForm submit function

        }); // end function

</script>
```

I think when the **return** is **true**, the form should submit (`action="..."`)... but nothing happens. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `return true;` in success callback, submit the FORM using DOM node method:

```
$("#loginForm").submit(function () {
    var data = $("#loginForm :input").serialize();
    var curl = "../view/index_valid.php";
    $.ajax({
        context: this, //>> set context
        url: curl,
        method: "post",
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            if (data === "logged") {
                this.submit(); //>> that will submit the FORM
            } /*else {
                return false; //>> returning false here is useless
            }*/
        }
        return false;
    });
}); // end loginForm submit function
```

Comment: I'm really sure, if i add `$(this).submit();` it will return to the same `$("#loginForm").submit(...)` function.

Comment: @JhonatanSandoval That's why i use here `this.submit();` not `$(this).submit()` and don't forget to set context option of ajax request. Of course, you cannot have any element inside FORM with attribute name equal to `submit` otherwise FORM method is overriden